# Android Volley And AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-volley

I've been reading that we dont need to use AsyncTask when working with volley. I had a question though, one of the button click in my activity triggers a HTTP request. Now in case my app is closed, will volley still be able to process that request.

When I launch my app again, is it possible to figure if my previous HTTP request was sent or not.

What would happen to the response? Will I be able to catch the response and maybe make some db updates (local to app)?

What is the right design to do these kind of http requests?

Also, in case I want to make some HTTP requests while the app is not launched, can I not use a background task to do all this with volley?

Comment: if you want to make some http calls when app is not on foreground or even ensure handing responses when user leave app during runtime I would suggest to pack up all networking features into some [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) (especially [ForegroundService](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use an AsyncTask or Thread for Volley because Volley does that for you.  So that's correct.

When you say your app is closed-  do you mean the app is in the background, or the app is terminated?  In the first case, the request will continue.  In the second, it will not, and any response coming in would be ignored at the OS layer because there's no listening app on the socket.  Also remember that apps not in the foreground can be killed by the OS at any time.

You can't send an HTTP request when your app isn't launched.  You can do so in a JobScheduler or WorkManager item, but then your app is launched, you just aren't showing a UI.

Comment: so in case I want to process responses while the app isnt closed, but is in background, shall I use Volley in some service?

Comment: @Kraken Volley can work, as can any other http library.  I highly recommend Retrofit over Volley, for a number of reasons, but either can do the job.

Comment: As for some service-  the main question is-  how long a time do you plan to have this running in the background, how many requests you will make?  If its a few seconds and a single request, you probably can just send it in your activity.  A few minutes, a Service will work.  If its 15 minutes later, you need a foreground service.  If its an hour later or you want to continually poll for updates, you really need to rethink how you're doing this and perhaps JobScheduler or WorkManager is the right tool for you.  Or push notifications.